# Subversion, Merging

Tags: svn, merge, branching-and-merging

First let me preface by saying, I've asked similar questions here before, and never gotten a good answer that solved my lack of knowledge/problem.

First, let me start this off with a branching strategy proposal.  This is what we have at work, and I'm happy to hear comments otherwise, and as to why this sucks.  But understand that it generally works for us.

We have 1 product.  For the sake of this example, lets call it "PRODUCT".  We run 2 concurrent development cycles.  A weekly maintenance cycle, where we fix non-pressing bugs, and a bi-weekly sprint.  There are 2 branches created from trunk called "Sprint" and "Maintenance"(shocking name choice I know!).  Also for urgent/blocker issues, fixes are made directly into trunk and pushed to production after testing.

9 times out of 10 when I try to reintegrate the sprint or maintenance back into the trunk I get LARGE amounts of conflicts.  On files that were never even worked on in one of the branches.  This then leads to lots of manual merging, which sucks, and tends to lead to more problems.

So I will issue command: svn merge --reintegrate http://repo/Sprint 
and while some files will update, I will have conflicts on files that are EXACTLY identical(via WinMerge).  I don't know what causes these conflicts.

How can I stop having these ridiculous conflicts?

Comment: Without a *specific* example of a sequence of SVN commands and corresponding edits that causes this problem, this is going to be pretty tricky to diagnose...

Comment: Also, could this be a line-endings issue?  A change in line-endings may well appear invisible in your visual diff tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One answer is to use many small feature branches, not two fixed branches. Your problem is that changes from your fixed branches get merged, and then you do some more changes on the fixed branches and those changes appear to conflict with the first merge, even when they really don't.

So either use many small feature branches, or switch to a DVCS like Mercurial or git which handles merging in a more intelligent way than SVN currently does.

Comment: Unfortunately since we use Atlassian studio, SVN is what we are stuck with.

Comment: @llaskin OK, so use feature branches. SVN is actually a pretty solid VCS - you should try using raw rcs, SCCP or pvcs, to name but three horrid VCSs of yesteryear.

Comment: OK.  so each branch, gets branched off of the trunk?  or should I keep the sprint and maint branches, and branch off the sprint/maint branches to make feature branches?  I can see this getting very complex very quickly regardless of whic way I go.

Comment: It's not complex if the branches are small - a feature branch might only be used for a few hours. But I'm probably not the best guy to advise on this, as I suspect you are not running a C++ application shop.

Comment: @llaskin: As soon as you do `svn merge --reintegrate`, the branch that you've merged from should no longer be used, as you can no longer do automated reintegration merges from it.  See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html.

Answer (score 1):

You might find Timpani Software's MergeMagician project interesting.  It is a branch management and automated merging solution that works with Subversion (and also Microsoft TFS).  You create publish/subscribe relationships between branches, and then the server automates the merges.

Frequent merging as MM facilitates will reduce the occurrence of merge conflicts, and when they do happen, MM provides a web-based mechanism for resolving them.

FYI, it is a commercial tool.  The only open source tool I've heard of that does anything close to this is Merge Fairy, but I don't think Merge Fairy is very actively developed.

Check it out at http://www.timpanisoftware.com.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably just need to merge from the trunk back into your branches instead of creating new branches... something like this:

Trunk
 --- Create Sprint

--- Merge Sprint into Trunk
 --- Merge Trunk into Sprint